# Historical vs. present self-classifications when writing about LGBTQ+ history

Tags: non-fiction, history, lgbt

I'm writing a short summary of LGBTQ+ history focusing on the lead up to the Stonewall Uprising, the event itself, and the first Pride march. I understand how to respectfully discuss LGBTQ+ people today. However, this sometimes clashes with historical self-classifications.

Two examples:

- As I understand it, terms like *transvestite* were more commonly used, even by the people themselves, in the 1960s and 1970s. Is it more appropriate to project a more modern term like *transgender* onto some who might have identified as *transvestite* in the 1960s, or should I use the language they used at the time? I know *transgender* and *transvestite* are not the same but if the latter isn’t used any more, which word do I use?
- The word *gay* was also used more broadly to cover all LGBTQ+ people during that time as well. So while specific groups like Mattachine Society would be referred to as *gay rights* irrespectively, the broader movement of that time is often also called *gay rights.* If I’m writing about the broader movement of that time, is it okay to call it the LGBTQ+ Rights Movement?

Part of the reason I ask is one of my sources is *Stonewall: The Riots That Sparked the Gay Revolution* by David Carter and, while that book was published in 2010, it still uses the language of the 1960s.

Comment: Transvestite refers to a person who likes to wear clothing of the opposite sex. Typically it meant a man dressing as a woman. These could be men happily married with kids so it wasn't the same as what trans means today. It would be helpful for you to at least get a dictionary printed in say the 1990s to understand how terms were used.

Comment: @DamionKeeling I understand the differences, but I also know that its not really a term that is used today. But that's my problem: transvestite is not really a term used today, but there isn't really an exact equivalent to what is used and so what word do I use?

Comment: What is your audience: academic historians, interested lay people, etc.? Also, does the book by David Carter say anything about its use of terminology?

Comment: @Rozgonyi I don't pretend to be an expert, but isn't "cross-dresser" a term used today that would describe what _transvestite_ was used for at the time?

Comment: Fallacy whether any of these terms were 'self classifications': https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVD8PxGg1ys  
I can't think where using an outdated (rejected) term would ever be appropriate, outside of direct quotes or the name of an organization. Your question suggests you don't understand the progression of civil rights – a percentage of any minority will be sensitive to misuse of outdated terms, harming your credibility to speak about their history. LGBTQ+ is a term **because** these are very disparate communities that were all being mislabeled – it's like you missed the whole point.

Comment: @wetcircuit: I understand the problem as this: Suppose there was a Meeting of Transvestites and a League for Transvestites, whose members comprised people that nowadays mostly identify as transgender, cross dressers, drag artists, or similar, i.e., different groups. Now, you need a short term to refer to the target audience of these organisations. “transgender, cross dressers, drag artists, or similar” is neither clearly the audience of those groups nor feasible. Thus *transvestite* (with an appropriate disclaimer why you are using this term) does not seem like an unreasonable choice.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft you are free to use whatever outdated words you want to describe anything.... The issue is not your semantic word choice, the issue is that you reveal ignorance of the subject through out-dated terminology. Usually, authors writing about historic subjects want to sound authoritative. The demographic for readers who prefer 'pre-Stonewall' terms is diminishing each year.

Comment: @wetcircuit: How do I or the asker reveal our ignorance? We both clearly state that we are aware that these terms aren’t used nowadays. Also, I don’t see the asker suggesting anything; they are merely asking what to do. Anyway, if your answer to the question is to always use modern terms, you should probably write that as an answer, and ideally explain how you would address problems as described by me or in the question when modern terms don’t map one-to-one to historically used terms.

Comment: @terdon:  Transvestite comes from the words "trans" which means "cross" and vestment which means "clothing." so they are synonyms of each other.   Not all people who crossdress are transgender or interested in transitioning.  Some just like clothing marketed to the other sex more than their own clothing.   In terms of connotation, cross-dressing often refers to dressing in a manner for performance (either part of your act, or the script.). While Transvestites are people who wear clothing atypical of their sex out of comfort and are not seeking to change their gender.

Comment: With respect to the LGBT+ movement, I am old enough to remember when it was "LGB" and the "T" and the "plus" getting added fairly recently.   I also know the term Bisexual meant something different (in the classic Star Trek episode "The Trouble with Tribbles" Dr. McCoy speculates that Tribbles are "Bisexual" which his definition would be understood to be a hermaphadite that can reproduce with itself (they are born pregnant)... not that it was sexually attracted to both genders.